# Allocating CPU and Bandwidth to users of a smart contract

Tags: smart-contract

Say if 20 accounts want to run actions against a smart contract however do not possess the CPU and Bandwidth required to complete them, therefore run into errors saying so.

How can the dApp developer of the smart contract delegate resources to these actions?

Can he specify that CPU and Bandwidth resources derived by these actions should be paid for by his contract?

Otherwise, should he delegate CPU and bandwidth directly to those who require it?

Answer (score 1):

Receiver pays for bandwidth/CPU. So you have to stake enough EOS on your contract account so you can service these 20 accounts.